# Is it possible to visualize a Sprint burndown chart (or Burnup chart) from outside of Azure DevOps?

Tags: powerbi, burndowncharts

I'm trying to generate a consolidated view in some tool like Power BI so the top management of my organization can visualize *in a single page* the actual health of the projects and teams (in order to avoid the need of entering each project space in Azure DevOps).

I have already consumed successfully the Azure DevOps data from Power BI and I did some consolidated charts like open work items, work items by status, open bugs and so on; but I have no idea of what is the best aproach to show burnup and burndown charts.

Is there a way of embed this kind of charts outside Azure DevOps?

PS: In Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-sprintburndown?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi) there is an example to generate a Sprint burndown chart manually (from Power BI) but from my point of view it isn't so complete like native Sprint burndown chart [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-sprint-burndown?view=azure-devops&tabs=remaining-work%2Cmay)

Thanks!!

Comment: hi @Abe just to let you know, i am also working on similar thing of what you're doing. I managed to have sprint burndown and sprint burnup, but problem i faced my sprint burndown will not go all the way to zero when the team has completely burnt everything. I am using the OData query suggested in MS docs, and i think the culprit is statecategory eq 'Completed'.